# RGB data collection from video file

Tags: c++, opencv, video

Just looking for thoughts on efficiency, but nothing in depth. I'll explain what I'm trying to do before asking a couple questions.

I'd like to be able to take a video file (not format specific) and "play" it in the background (not on screen), while reading and outputting RGB data of a particular pixel in the current frame of the "playing" video - frame by frame - in real time.

I've looked into ways of doing this using OpenCV a little bit, but I figured I'd ask for input here while I continue researching. So, question:

With what methods can this be implemented, and what would be the most efficient / resource light method?

Note: Any major language is fine, but I'm most experienced in C++.

Thanks!
-Carlisle

Comment: Outputting that pixel to where? For what purpose? What platform/OS?

Comment: [`VideoCapture` docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) -- should be trivial to change that example to read a file, and modify the loop body so it outputs the desired pixel instead of what it does now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help.

```
    VideoCapture cap("videofile");

if(!cap.isOpened()
{
return -1;
}
    Mat img;

    while(1)
    {

    cap >> img;

    for (int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++) {

                Vec3b intensity = img.at<Vec3b>(j, i);

                uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
                uchar green = intensity.val[1];
                uchar red = intensity.val[2];
            }

        }

imshow("show", img);
    if(cap.empty())
                break;
    waitKey(30);

    }
```

Comment: It'd probably be better to check if `cap` is empty **before** dumping its contents. Also, `waitkey()` is not necessary if not displaying the file.